# CPython - print traceback

Tags: python, c++, cpython

How can I convert a traceback object to its string representation in CPython?
I tried this but the output is not very useful.

```
    PyObject *type, *value, *traceback;
    PyErr_Fetch(&type, &value, &traceback);

    PyObject* strTrace = PyObject_Repr(traceback);
    pyStrTrace = PyUnicode_AsEncodedString(strTrace, "utf-8", "strict");
    Py_XDECREF(strTrace);
    const char* sTrace = PyBytes_AS_STRING(pyStrTrace);
```

Content of `sTrace`:

```
 <traceback object at 0x000002594A5CC598>
```

Comment: You have to use the `traceback.format_exception` python function. Invoke it from C++ by importing the `traceback` module and getting a handle to the `format_exception` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One comment suggested to import `traceback` python module which would most certainly work well but I prefer a C++ only solution so I came up with this snippet. Hopefully, someone finds it useful.

First include Python's `<frameobject.h>`

```
if (PyTraceBack_Check(traceback))
{
    PyTracebackObject* traceRoot = (PyTracebackObject*)traceback;
    PyTracebackObject* pTrace = traceRoot;
    
    while (pTrace != NULL)
    {
        PyFrameObject* frame = pTrace->tb_frame;
        PyCodeObject* code = frame->f_code;

        int lineNr = PyFrame_GetLineNumber(frame);
        const char *sCodeName = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(code->co_name);
        const char *sFileName = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(code->co_filename);

        printf("at %s (%s:%d); ", sCodeName, sFileName, lineNr);
        pTrace = pTrace->tb_next;
    }        
}
```

---

As of Python 3.11 `frame->f_code` is nolonger possible (PyFrameObject was moved private). It's suggested in the [changelog](https://docs.python.org/3.11/whatsnew/3.11.html#c-api-changes) that `PyFrame_GetCode(frame)` is used instead.

Likewise, this removes the need to include `<frameobject.h>`

For backwards compatibility you can implement this function yourself:

```c
#if PY_VERSION_HEX < 0x030900B1
#include <frameobject.h>
static inline PyCodeObject* PyFrame_GetCode(PyFrameObject *frame)
{
    Py_INCREF(frame->f_code);
    return frame->f_code;
}
#endif
```